# Размытые логотипы и иконки на сайте

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Перегуглил уже весь интернет и всё равно не могу понять почему логотип и иконки размытые [image: иконки и логотип в низком разрешении] Не смотря на то, что все файлы в формате svg.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробовали вставлять не через тег `<img />`, а через `<svg />`?

Comment: Еще есть такой вариант, что ваши иконки, это PNG-шки в SVG обертке. То есть изначально это были растровые изображения, их экспорт в SVG формате не делает их векторными.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Действительно я экспортировал данные изображения в формате svп из figma изначально они были в формате png.